# Generic Enum/EnumSet Troubles

Tags: java, generics, enums, enumset

I have a class and function defined as the following:

```
public class Site {
    public EnumSet<?> contents;

    public void determineStates(Site a, Site b) {
        this.contents.clear();
        this.contents.addAll(a.contents);
        this.contents.addAll(b.contents);
        a.contents.removeAll(b.contents);
        this.contents.removeAll(a.contents);
    }
}
```

For both addAll operations, Eclipse is giving me the following error message:

```
The method addAll(Collection<? extends capture#6-of ?>) in the type AbstractCollection<capture#6-of ?> is not applicable for the arguments (EnumSet<capture#7-of ?>)
```

Essentially I need some form of `Enum` generics and I have just been frustrated with what appear to be limitations. I have a number of `Enum` types that are incompatible but I desire some container that can hold any type.

I recognize that in this code there is no way to be certain that `a`, `b`, and `contents` are all of the same `Enum` type, however in actual implementation this should not be problematic.

Any thoughts and possible methods to address my generic `Enum` problem would be valuable and I would be immensely grateful for your help. Thanks in advance.

Comment: If a b and c are of the same Enum type, then Site should have its own generic parameter.  If not, this can't be done with EnumSets.

Comment: @LouisWasserman In implementation, yes, all variables would be of the same Enum type. Do you mind explaining how to create a generic parameter for Site?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The Site class should be generic:

```
public class Site<E extends Enum<E>> {
    public EnumSet<E> contents;

    public void determineStates(Site<E> a, Site<E> b) {
        this.contents.clear();
        this.contents.addAll(a.contents);
        this.contents.addAll(b.contents);
        a.contents.removeAll(b.contents);
        this.contents.removeAll(a.contents);
    }
}
```